# Using pci_map_single for multiple dma transfer

Tags: linux, dma

I am going through the kernel source documentation at this link http://lwn.net/2001/0712/a/dma-interface.php3. It mentions that pci_map_single can be used for only single transfer. I am writing a PCI driver and device writes to buffer 4KB data at every 500 us . After that it will give an interrupt. I tried to work with pci_alloc_consistent but it is constantly producing error stating "coherent DMA mask  is smaller than system GFP_DMA mask arm". My question is how can I use pci_map_single for multiple dma transfers. Or what is correct way for using pci_alloc_coherent?

Comment: I found this question and which is exactly the same but with no exact answer. Anybody please help us.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979107/linux-kernel-is-it-ok-to-leave-a-streaming-dma-mapping-open-indefinitely/31973856#31973856

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to do multiple DMA transfers via the same buffer, you can just pci_unmap_single and then map the dma again.
But you need to store the dma address every time, so you can unmap it.